# bootstrap 4.2.1 `bundle install` error occurred while installing ffi (1.10.0)

Tags: npm, terminal, bootstrap-4, ffi

I am trying to run `bundle install` on bootstrap 4.2.1 and get this error

```
An error occurred while installing ffi (1.10.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.10.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  jekyll-redirect-from was resolved to 0.14.0, which depends on
    jekyll was resolved to 3.8.5, which depends on
      jekyll-sass-converter was resolved to 1.5.2, which depends on
        sass was resolved to 3.7.3, which depends on
          sass-listen was resolved to 4.0.0, which depends on
            rb-inotify was resolved to 0.10.0, which depends on
              ffi
```

**What I tried:**

- did everything on https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap
- ran `gem install ffi -v '1.10.0' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` and `gem install ffi`
- installed / updated ruby
- brew install openssl libyaml libffi
- xcode-select --install
- Tried everything 20 times all over

People say this is a mac Mojave issue... I searched all other questions and there are no working fixes.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Issue was fixed after installing xcode from mac store that weighs over 10gb just for couple of dependesis

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by [vladhadzhiyski](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/647#issuecomment-466683624) to run `brew reinstall libffi` worked for me:

```
$ brew reinstall libffi
==> Reinstalling libffi
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/libffi-3.2.1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring libffi-3.2.1.mojave.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
libffi is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because some formulae require a newer version of libffi.
For compilers to find libffi you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
For pkg-config to find libffi you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/libffi/3.2.1: 16 files, 296.8KB
$ export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib"
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/libffi/lib/pkgconfig"
$ bundle install
```